# read pixel color in a panel vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, bitmap, panel

I am fairly new to VS 2010, so kindly provide suitable code/explanations/links.

I have a panel `sked_panel` in a form which is filled with colored blocks as shown in the picture. I want to find out the percentage of red, blue, green and orange in the panel.

Options I have contemplated thus far:

- Use for loop to read through the panel and use a function to read each pixel. I can do that myself.
- Save the panel as a Bitmap and then use a similar function.

The first option is preferable to me (and is potentially less computation intensive).

Here's how the `sked_panel` looks:

[image]

Comment: How did the colors get there in the first place?

Comment: Just don't, nothing good will happen when the panel is overlapped by another window.  If you can't determine the color from the way the panel is painted then draw into a bitmap first and paint that bitmap.  Now you can poke the bitmap for a color.

Comment: Before counting, drawing and reading colors from a bitmap, why not just use the data first used to generate the colors to calc stats?